# Geospatial Database Cloud Server

Tags: database, google-app-engine, cloud, geospatial

Are there any cloud hosting solutions for geospatial data? I am currently writing a directory style app where businesses can sign up and then users can find nearby ones.

I am considering Google App Engine for this, but from what I can tell the GeoModel code is quite expensive (up to tens of thousands of dollars a year) to run since Google updated the pricing of App Engine. It doesn't seem like App Engine's database is really suited to this kind of query (though the SQL solution may be an answer).

I was hoping to find a service where I could send off a HTTP request to add data (a business' id, name and icon url) to a database, and then another one to find a list of businesses that are nearby to a given point. A service is preferable as this is work done for a client and we would like the solution to be managed with as little interaction from us or the client needed as possible.

EDIT:
I just found [cartodb.com](http://cartodb.com) which uses PostgreSQL and is reasonably priced. Are the any other alternatives?

Comment: "Up to tens of thousands of dollars a year" is a pretty meaningless figure in isolation. Any solution could cost that - or more - with enough traffic.

Comment: That is for the level of traffic that we are expecting, from what I can see other people are reporting for similar levels of traffic. (I can't divulge precisely how much sorry.)

Comment: Then it's still pretty meaningless to anyone but yourself. If you want to quantify things, you need to specify things per-query or per-update.

Comment: To be fair, I wasn't asking for cheaper solutions, just alternatives (which some people have thankfully provided).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The App Engine [Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/) (currently in Experimental) supports GeoPoints and geosearch, and is great for exactly the kind of query that you describe.

See the Google Developers Academy (GDA) [App Engine](https://developers.google.com/academy/apis/cloud/appengine/) Search API classes for a bit more info and an example as well.

Comment: This ia great! The client may get upset if the app suddenly breaks after release however. If only it was stable!

Comment: I'm going to accept this because it is so close to what we are looking for, and will probably be the best solution in the future when it is stable.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iriscouch.com/ is a cloud-based host for CouchDB and they support the geocouch extensions for CouchDB to store geoJSON data and perform spatial queries.

Answer (score 0):

We have decided to go with [cartodb.com](http://cartodb.com) because it looks like they have a good price to ease of use ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned going with CartoDB, which is a good choice with a nice UI.

Just adding, if you were just looking for a scalable backend, you could use StormDB. It is a cloud hosted SQL database with geospatial extensions. You data is automatically distributed amongst multiple nodes for write, read, and parallel query scalability.